# MVC Razor View - Displaying Modified Date instead of Created Date if it is not empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC Core View, I am trying to display the Date Modified instead of Date Created if it is not empty.

So, I wrote like the following

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.DateModified.HasValue ? item.DateModified : item.DateCreated))
```

But got an error saying that

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions
```

So, instead of that I changed it to the following and it works.

```
@(item.DateModified.HasValue ? item.DateModified.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : item.DateCreated.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

However, the problem is that I have to re-specify the format of the date which I already did in Model Declaration.  If not, it's showing data in dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss format because I am not using **DisplayFor** anymore.

Another possibility is that I could use the ViewModel and add a new property to handle this kind of special text.

May I know if there is a better way to handle this kind of scenario?

Comment: The view model possibility that you are suggesting is the best way to handle this.

Comment: A view model is always best, but you could always use `@if (item.DateModified.HasValue) { @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.DateModified) } else { @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.DateCreated) }`

Comment: It seems better to use an helper property in the model instead of putting logic in the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following helper property in your view model, which will take care of your issue and formatting

```
    //Considering your DateCreated is not nullable

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")] 
    public DateTime DisplayDate
    {
       get { return DateModified.HasValue ? DateModified.Value : DateCreated; }
    }
```

Comment: Am I missing anything?  It doesn't display in the correct format unless I put [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]

Comment: Yeah, You have to decorate the DisplayFormat attribute as well